# how to add a vue-cli project repository in github pages?

Tags: javascript, github, webpack, vue.js, github-pages

I'm trying to add a vuejs project built using webpack in gituhub pages. I have created a repository.

[renamed dist folder as a doc folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysSdf.png).

[changed the settings-> github pages-> source to master-branch docs folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/URpWV.png)

[this is the docs folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjCTA.png)

Everything has done properly, the project is working fine when I'm running it in dev server. but when I pushed in github pages it is not working at all.

When I opened the link of the repository page i'm getting a blank window. I checked in the browser console.

I'm getting this error in browser:
[image: error].
Please find a solution for this please. More vue projects are there to upload and i'm unable to upload one at least.

Comment: I followed this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-gh-pages and it worked

Comment: Sorry, I figured it out. Thank you